# Changes made in Active Directory aren't reflected in Exchange Management Console 2010

Tags: exchange-2010

For the last week I have been trying to work out why our Outlook address book displayed old information, at first I thought it was the Offline address book but today I noticed that if I look at the users in the Exchange Management Console (Exchange 2010) all the old data is shown.

How can I force Exchange to re-read Active Directory?

Thanks
Sean

Answer (score 1):

The Exchange Management Console is reading directly from Active Directory, not from any kind of cache within Exchange itself.

Check that the changes replicated correctly across all of your domain controllers?